# Django data from context not showing in template

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

Im stuck with a template context in Django. In my template I display information about a team and I also want to display players from this team. In context I pass players from team but then in template when I want to display this data it doesn't work. I tried to add also some example data like `"test":123` and display it in template like `{{test}}` but it also doesn't work.
**views.py***

```
def team_profile(request, name):
    team = Team.objects.get(name=name)
    player_list_filtered = []
    player_list = User.objects.all()
    for player in player_list:
        if player.profile.team.name == team.name:
            player_list.append(player)

    context = {
        'team': team,
        'players': player_list_filtered,
        'test': 123
    }

    return render(request, 'blog/team_profile.html', context)
```

**team_profile.html***

```
{% block content %}
<div class="d-flex align-items-start flex-column content-section">
<img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ team.image.url }}">
    <h1>{{team.name}}</h1>
    <h3>Mecze: {{team.matches}}</h3>
    <h3>League: {{team.league}}</h3>
    {% for player in players %}
        <h3>{{player.first_name}}</h3>
    {% endfor %}

    <p>Test: {{test}}</p>

</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Here is my result

[image: Here is my result]

Comment: You pass player_list_filtered but it is empty. I suppose you want to pass player_list in your context

Comment: When I pass players_list it also doesnt work. Look, even when I pass `test` is doesn't show

Comment: add a print statement  in your loop in the views to check if your list still empty after the append. something like print(player.first_name) depending on what you have ,that way you can precisely know if the your loop is acually workin

Answer (score 0):

Replace this: `player_list.append(player)` with this: `player_list_filtered .append(player)` then your list should store valid players.

Comment: Problem was different, nothing from context in views was showing in DetailView. I had to override get_context_data in my detail views class. Thanks for help anyway!